# Design Query on Azure Table Storage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-table-storage

I have 2 C# MVC models

1. SignalModel
2. DeviceSignalModel

`SignalModel` ==> *contains the properties of Signal say MasterSignal*

`DeviceSignalModel` ==> *contains all signal properties pertaining to a Device*

So both are expected to have same properties except that `DeviceSignalModel` need to have an additional property of DeviceID.

The Model `SignalModel` will have columns ==> id,name,unit,range ...
representing the Azure Storage Table `signal`.

I use below to get the data from table `signal`

```
TableOperation retOp = TableOperation.Retrieve<SignalModel>(..,..,..);
TableResult tr = table.Execute(retOp);
```

I have another Azure Storage Table `devicesignal` and its represented by a model `DeviceSignalModel` 
I have designed the Model as

```
public class DeviceSignalModel : TableEntity, IAzureTableStorage
    {
        //public int DeviceSignalKey { get; set; }// RowKey for Unique Key
        //public string DeviceSignalID { get; set; }// PartitionKey of Storage Table Device

        public SignalModel Signal { get; set; }//<===== (A) Model here right?
```

And to get data from devicesignal I use the below

```
TableOperation retOp = TableOperation.Retrieve<DeviceSignalModel>(..,..,..);
TableResult tr = table.Execute(retOp);
```

With the above query I don't get values of columns represented within SignalModel from devicesignal table(statement (A) above). I get a null for property Signal.

**My Query**

1.Is the statement (A) in above snippet not possible?

2. Should all the properties in SignalModel be explicitly placed inside the DeviceSignalModel (instead of having an object Signal as property?
3. If so what is the best option to avoid adding same properties in both Signal and DeviceSignal when there is a future change (add property) to Signal Table.

Comment: Azure Table Storage is not relational database and corresponding API is not like Entity Framework, so you should do your intentions manually: fetch separately `DeviceSignalModel` and then corresponding `SignalModel` instances or store them together in same table.

Comment: signalModel is not a supported type on table storage either, for that you need documentDb or convert you object to string.    TableStorage is very limited on what TYPES it can store

Answer (score 1):

You can not make your custom `SignalModel` as Property type. If you want to maintain `SignalModel` type object information in a `DeviceSignalModel` entity, you can try to serialize the `SignalModel` type object into JSON string and save it as property value of `DeviceSignalModel` entity. Or as davethecoder said, if possible, you can use [Azure DocumentDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-introduction) to store your data.

Besides, to implement relationships between **Signal** and **DeviceSignal** in Azure Table service, as you mentioned, placing particular properties of SignalModel entity inside the DeviceSignalModel entity could be a approach. In addition, you can refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-design-guide#modelling-relationships) to know about modelling relationships and table design patterns in Azure Table service.